# Tomcat 9 on port 443 working with only root which can be hamful

Tags: tomcat9

After so many reading of serverfault.com articles I have successfully configured my tomcat 9 on port 443.

But problem is 443 is an privileged port in which i added root user in below tomcat.service  but how i can avoid this as i want to give permission to tomcat user for just only one service. I hope you understand my issue and will advise the best answer.

```
vim /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service


[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking



############## I added root user here ##########################
**User=root
Group=root**

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187726/how-do-daemons-like-apache-or-bind-open-ports-below-1024

Comment: Its very limited and has incomplete answer as i already read the article thats why writing another for complete guidance and solution.

Comment: anyone can reply on this waiting

Comment: Why does using root capabilities not apply to your situation?

Comment: There is also [tomcat 9 configuration for port 443](https://serverfault.com/questions/969191/tomcat-9-configuration-for-port-443?rq=1)

Comment: Not working at All i have tried all the above methods from 5 days but no luck at All.

Comment: Tomcat 9 Service is working fine with user tomcat and group tomcat but problem is that with tomcat 443 port is not opening but when i added root the port is opening.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443  this is the url what i need but this is still incomplete answer can someone please guide in detail how i can use net_cap for tomcat 443

Answer (score 2):

You can run Tomcat (or anything) as non-root and still bind to system ports if you have granted the CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE capability set. You can do this in your systemd unit by adding [`AmbientCapabilities=`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#AmbientCapabilities=) in the `[Service]` section:

```
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
```

Obviously you will also need to remove `User=` and `Group=`.

You should also consider using [`NoNewPrivileges=true`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#NoNewPrivileges=) to restrict the app from elevating its privileges.

Comment: Appreciated ! Dear Michael Hampton, after followed you instructions my issue has resolved i would like to say thanks to understand my issue and your dedication for said problem. Thanks you very much.

Comment: @Noor Thank you! You can mark it as solved by clicking the outline of the tick mark so that it turns solid green.